How to get HRESULT instead exception from a COM-method
I'm using the IAMCameraControl.GetRange method in C#. The description says nothing about exceptions. Only about returning the HRESULT error value. But in my code a COMException occurs, inside of which an HRESULT is specified.
Why throw an exception instead of returning an error? How to fix it?
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComImport]
[Guid("C6E13370-30AC-11d0-A18C-00A0C9118956")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAMCameraControl
{
    int GetRange([In] CameraControlProperty property, [In][Out] ref int pMin, [In][Out] ref int pMax, [In][Out] ref int pSteppingDelta, [In][Out] ref int pDefault, [In][Out] ref int pCapsFlag);
    int Set([In] CameraControlProperty property, [In] int lValue, [In] int flags);
    int Get([In] CameraControlProperty property, [In][Out] ref int lValue, [In][Out] ref int flags);
}


The documentation says you are using a deprecated feature. Maybe the documentation is just outdated? Maybe the underlying implementation changed? Or maybe it's a transitive dependency that has changed and throws exceptions now?

@Good Night Nerd Pride
DirectShow is deprecated. Now it is replaced by the Media Foundation. But DirectShow continues to work.

Just use PreserveSig attribute
[ComImport, Guid("c6e13370-30ac-11d0-a18c-00a0c9118956"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAMCameraControl
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetRange(...)
    
    ...
}


The correct way to handle HResult is to have it throw an exception, as it's an "exceptional" result. .NET has special handling for HResult, to transform the HResult into an exception, which is more idiomatic in .NET.
You could use [PreserveSig] to suppress this handling, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.
So remove the int return value. Also [ComVisible] should not be specified, and the [in][Out] ref values should be [Out] out
[ComImport]
[Guid("C6E13370-30AC-11d0-A18C-00A0C9118956")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAMCameraControl
{
    void GetRange([In] CameraControlProperty property, [Out] out int pMin, [Out] out int pMax, [Out] out int pSteppingDelta, [Out] out int pDefault, [Out] out int pCapsFlag);
    void Set([In] CameraControlProperty property, [In] int lValue, [In] int flags);
    void Get([In] CameraControlProperty property, [Out] out int lValue, [Out] out int flags);
}


In my case, one of the errors is not critical.

That's what a try catch is for. Unless the code is performance critical you should write it in the clearest manner possible.

exception+try+catch is nice choice in OOP design terms but costs a lot (when raised) in terms of cpu cycles. There are many cases with COM when you just want to check the error code, as it's much simpler. Also w/o PreserveSig you can't check for success values (S_FALSE and other) easily.

@SimonMourier For a single call that's not worth thinking about. I did say "unless the code is performance critical". Yes if it's done in a heavy loop, or you know that one of the codes is not an actual exception then it may make sense to use PreserveSig.


"Why throw an exception instead of returning an error?"

It is because using exceptions is the common error handling method in .NET environment.

"How to fix it?"

The COMException class contains a HResult property with the HRESULT value.
You should therefore catch the exception as usuall in .NET, and then use this property to determine the nature of the error, as mentioned in the COM documentation.

Yes, I am know about HRESULT inside COMException. But the goal is that no exception should occur.

@ffvideoner yes but why ? As both myself and Charlieface wrote, exceptions are the idiomatic way to handle such errors in .NET, and therefore I think extracting the HRESULT from the exception is the way to go. If you have a good reason to avoid it, I think you should add that info to your question.

Because in my case one of the errors is not critical.

You can still continue the execution if the HRESULT is not critical in your case. You should simply catch the exception, examine the HRESULT and branch accordingly. It is up to you of course, but I wouldn't recommend writing in a non-idiomatic way unless you have a good reason.

It is more convenient for me if Visual Studio shows COM-exceptions, except for one error in one place. Maybe it's bad style.

I didn't downvote. I only upvoted the correct answer. I explained in question what I knew about the value of HRESULT.

@ffvideoner it wasn't clear to me that you know how to extract it, and anyway I believe that good answers on StackOverflow should direct developers to writing code according to good practices as well (and not only answer immediate questions).

I have nothing against it.
